# CSS/HTML Navi bar - active/current link

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an active/current link on my nav bar.

In the HTML, there an element with a `class="current"` attribute on one of the elements.

I want that element to have a background if the class is active/current

```
<ul id="trans-nav">
    <li  class="current">
        <a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What do i need in my CSS?

```
#trans-nav {
    list-style-type: none; 
    height: 40px; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;
}
#trans-nav {
    list-style-type: none; 
    height: 40px; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
}
#trans-nav li {
    float: left; 
    position: relative; 
    padding: 0; 
    line-height: 40px;
}
#trans-nav li:hover {
    background-position: 0 -40px;
}
#trans-nav li a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 0 15px; 
    color: #666666; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
#trans-nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#F36F25; 
    color: #eeeeee;
}
#trans-nav li active {
    background-color:#F36F25; 
    color: #eeeeee;
}
#trans-nav li ul {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
}
#trans-nav li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1; 
}
#trans-nav li ul li {
    float: none; 
    position: static; 
    height: 0; 
    line-height: 0; 
    background: none;
}
#trans-nav li:hover ul li {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
#trans-nav li ul li a {
    background: #EEEEEE;
}
#trans-nav li ul li a:hover {
    background: #666666;
    color:#EEEEEE;
}

#trans-nav li { -webkit-transition: all 0.2s; }
#trans-nav li a { -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; }
#trans-nav li ul { -webkit-transition: all 1s; }
#trans-nav li ul li { -webkit-transition: height 0.5s; }
```

I have tried this but it didn't work:

```
#trans-nav li active {
    background-color:#F36F25; 
    color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried .current a { }

Comment: You should post the code on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) so people can fiddle with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so close!

```
#trans-nav li .active {
background-color:#F36F25; 
color: #eeeeee;
}
```

You just forgot the `.` on `.active`

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QthpX/)

Answer (score 0):

Your css would need the . indicator for Class, and the link selector.

```
#trans-nav li.current a {
    background-color:#F36F25; 
    color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Comment: just tried here but still not working :( http://jsfiddle.net/charliejsford/Erzn2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the first one will target the li with the `current` class, the second will target the link for `current` (About Us) and won't flow down to the sub-menu due to the direct descendant selector `>`.

```
#trans-nav .current {
    background-color:#F36F25; 
}
#trans-nav .current > a {
    color: #eeeeee;
}
```